# Subscribe form implementation in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, subscription

I'm currently involved in the project, where it is needed to implement the subscription option for Bootstrap.
Currently I have the following code:

```
<center>
 <form class="form-inline" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control transparent" placeholder="Enter your email">
   </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-fill">Subscribe</button>
 </form>
</center>
```

How can I make the "Subscribe" button to link to an email? Basically, how can find out if somebody had subscribed to the newsletter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't enough information here to actually answer your question as we have no idea of what back end code that form is being posted to.

But I will give it a try...

In my view you have 2 options. It depends on how the backend of your project is structured and what the purpose of the 'subscribe' button is.

If you are just wanting to subscribe someone to a mailing list and send them emails on a regular basis, the easiest thing to do is to use [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/monkey-rewards/?utm_source=freemium_newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=monkey_rewards&aid=83317f731cbb92a24392adb90&afl=1) instead of building your own infrastructure. Once you have created a list you then use the form builder to build the form and then you can copy the html of the form into a page on your site. You **will** need re-write a bit of the form code to use bootstrap as their generated form code does not use bootstrap, however that is not so hard to do. From there you can log on to MailChimp and easily see how many subscribers in your list.

If you want to roll your own solution you need to store each email address in a database that's under your control. Typically in an MVC Web app the form which is in the view later will post to a controller and from there the Controller takes the data (the Model) and invokes some service on the backend to store it in the database or otherwise do something with it. Then you would need a page which calls the an appropriate method in a service in the backend and returns the model and the view and displays it.

Using MailChimp is far less work and very quick to get started, less for you to maintain and it works really well.

Comment: Thanks @james-scott-tayler for your answer! I may not explain myself in a clear way, that's true. Will it be possible to have the input email send to company email in order to count the number of future subscribers? I know it may be not the most elegant way.

Comment: Figured out my problem with this article: http://azmind.com/2015/09/18/mailchimp-subscribe-form-bootstrap-landing-page/ . Thanks @james for suggesting the MailChimp that really helped me a lot.